# JAVASCRIPT if statement won't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am making a game where you are supposed to be taken to the second level after you have 10 points on level 1. Here is my function to add points, it has an if statement to take you to the next level (game.html) when your score is 10.

```
<script>
function addScore(){

scoreDiv = document.getElementById("score");

scoreDiv.innerHTML ++;

if(scoreDiv == 10) {
window.open("Game.html");

}
else {
}
}
</script>
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: You're comparing the reference to the DOM element (`scoreDiv`) to a number. A reference to a DOM node will never be equal to a number.

Comment: Use .value to get what you want

Comment: var scoreDiv = document.getElementById("score").value; use it

Comment: @Prashant if it's really a `<div>` then it won't have a "value" property.

Answer (score 2):

So what you are doing wrong is you are comparing an element to a number, so it will NEVER be equal. What you want to do is `scoreDiv.value == 10`

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the value in `scoreDiv.innerHTML`, but then you are checking the value in `scoreDiv`, which is the element itself.

You should check the value that you increased:

```
if(scoreDiv.innerHTML == 10) {
```